# Can I use the Foursquare API to find 'general use' photos of venues?

Tags: api, foursquare, photos

When presenting a Foursquare venue in my application, I would like to show a image of each venue that is a good representation of the place - the kind of photo that the management might use for advertising or you might see in a review of the restaurant.  This is generally a wide shot of the interior.  Many venue photos in foursquare are unsurprisingly of groups of people and give little idea about the 'feel' of the place.  Has anyone worked out a good way to get more generally representative photos?  It would be specifically useful to get photos that have been provided by the venue management.

Comment: I assume you can only do this on "claimed" venues... otherwise would be a wild goose chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to distinguish photos uploaded by the venue manager and any other user. You can however, distinguish photos made by friends of a venue. photos made by other people and photos made by a specific person.